# error code 1 when deploying a prismic app on vercel

Tags: javascript, next.js, deployment, vercel, prismic

I'm trying to deploy my prismic app on vercel, but receiving that error :

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /vercel/path0/node_modules/@scarf/scarf
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node ./report.js
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /vercel/.npm/_logs/2023-07-22T16_55_53_186Z-debug-0.log
Error: Command "npm install" exited with 1
```

I have no error when I npm run build on local.
Puppeteer is not installed in my app itself but seems to be on slice-machine. I don't know if it's mandatory or can be uninstalledd.

Does anyone have already experienced the same problem?

Comment: I tried to create a new project and it worked fine. I don't understand what wrong with my first one